# What does the capital letters mean in this css tag: font-family "URWPSK+ArialMT"?:

Tags: html, css, fonts, tags

I am looking at this html/css style and am trying to figure out what the capital letters represent in the `font-family`: the `URWPSK` in `font-family: "URWPSK+ArialMT"`. Thanks!

```
.stl_42 {
    font-size: 1.08em;
    font-family: "URWPSK+ArialMT";
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 1.117187em;
}
.stl_43 {
    font-size: 0.63em;
    font-family: "EQHMIL+Arial-BoldMT";
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 1.117188em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. That is just a font name. They used own fonts.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer. So the "EQHMIL" in front of font-family: "EQHMIL+Arial-BoldMT"; is just like a hash key to give the arial font a unique font name? So the font-family itself is still Arial-BoldMT? Thanks.

Comment: I think they probably converted the font to font-face from somewhere. And the generator put that hashy text at the beginning of the font.